# Querying password hash from mysql database returns buffer array of decimal numbers instead of string

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, hash

I'm developing an API using Node.js and MySql.

I have hashed a password using `bcrypt` and stored it into a MySql database using the `VARBINARY` data type.

When I query the password hash through the command line I receive the output i want. 
However when I query via my API, I get a different format.
I think it is a decimal format.

**How can I get the hash in string format again?**

Result using command line:
[image: Query using command line]

Result via api

```js
[
    {
        "pwd": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                36,
                50,
                98,
                36,
                49,
                48,
                36,
                71,
                46,
                107,
                74,
                75,
                55,
                110,
                54,
                49,
                70,
                77,
                120,
                112,
                121,
                52,
                103,
                73,
                78,
                83,
                81,
                79,
                101,
                98,
                57,
                105,
                89,
                48,
                105,
                86,
                113,
                86,
                81,
                113,
                114,
                104,
                69,
                84,
                78,
                103,
                117,
                105,
                65,
                53,
                102,
                83,
                115,
                115,
                54,
                53,
                100,
                57,
                112,
                121
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Code:

```js
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    db.query(
        `select pwd from users where username='${req.body.username}';`,
        (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
            return res.json(results);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Be sure to use *prepared statements with placeholder values* to provide a clean separation between query and data so you can avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is supported by Sequelize. Here you should have `username=?`. Additionally the `;` is for interactive mode only and should be omitted in queries like this.

Comment: You probably need to cast pwd as varchar, e.g., `SELECT CAST(pwd AS VARCHAR) AS password ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a Buffer back because that's the best representation of a `VARBINARY` column. If you want to convert you can call [`toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to get a string.

What you really want is a `VARCHAR` column as the Bcrypt output will always be simple ASCII, there's no need for a binary-type column.